# Как разместить элементы друг под другом?

Tags: html, css

Есть `div`, в котором элемент отцентрирован таким образом:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Понадобилось в него добавить ещё несколько элементовов, но при добавлении выходит ерунда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разместить Restart и ВРЕМЯ друг под другом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо задать направление:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А что можно сделать с большим расстоянием между ними?

Просто, оно великовато получается

Comment: @DGDays при стилях, указанных в вопросе, расстояний быть не должно. Если есть еще стили, то нужно смотреть уже их